# Visual Basic Check Digit Generator

Tags: vb.net

I've been asked to make a programme on Visual Basic which takes an 8 digit number from a text box and generates a check digit to form a 9 digit check number.

The programme should take the first number in the text box and multiply it by 10, the second by 9, the third by 8 and so on until you're multiplying the eigth digit by 2. From that you add all of the answers together, divide them by nine and get an answer with the remainder. From the remainder, I think you subtract it from 9 and then you get the digit.

Would anyone be able to give me any pointers as to how to isolate the digits (I think the midpoint's involved), multiply them by the various numbers and calculate the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use len and left function of visual basic in a loop
(Not sure about the version of Visual Basic)

```
MyString=Text1.text
StringLen = Len(MyString)
total=0

for a=1 to StringLen 
result=Left(MyString, StringLen-1)
if a=1
total=resultx10
elseif a=2
total=total+resultx9
..
..
..
endif
next
```

Hope this helps